# Correct syntax of printing array objects inside array React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm new to `ReactJS` library, and I'm trying to print the following structure of array:

```
Main Array[
  Array0[
     Object0{
      questions: "question1",
      answer1: "answer1",
      answer2: "answer2"
     },
     Object1{
      questions: "question1",
      answer1: "answer1",
      answer2: "answer2"
     }
  ]
]
```

This structure of array is hold in state called `question`, I have tried to create new functional component and print it on user screen but I received the following error:

> TypeError: quest[0].map is not a function

My target is to print Object0 and Object1 data.

```
const [question, setQuestion] = useState([]);
setQuestion([
  [
      {
       questions: "question1",
       answer1: "answer1",
       answer2: "answer2"
      },
      {
       questions: "question2",
       answer1: "answer1",
       answer2: "answer2"
      }
  ]
]);
//Component
const QuestionsComponent = function questions(){
    return (
        <div>
            {
                question.map(function (quest){
                    quest[0].map(function(ques){
                        return quest.questions;
                    })
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}


 return(
   <>
    <QuestionsComponent />
   </>
 );
```

What is the correct approach to print array of objects inside of array?

Comment: Instead of defining the initial state as empty array, just pass the array you pass to `setQuestion()` to the `useState()`. Also you probably meant to pass `question` as a prop to `QuestionsComponent`

Comment: @Yousaf thats right, but It's not my full code, I receive the array of objects from functions that aren't related to this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `map` over `question`:

```
question.map(function (quest){
```

The `quest` variable will be each element of that array.  Which in this case that element is:

```
[
  {
   questions: "question1",
   answer1: "answer1",
   answer2: "answer2"
  },
  {
   questions: "question2",
   answer1: "answer1",
   answer2: "answer2"
  }
]
```

An array of objects.  So referencing an element of that array (such as `quest[0]`) would be:

```
{
   questions: "question1",
   answer1: "answer1",
   answer2: "answer2"
}
```

Which indeed isn't an array and has no `.map()`.

It sounds like you wanted to `map` over `quest`, not an element of it:

```
quest.map(function(ques){
    return quest.questions;
})
```

Ultimately it looks like your variable naming is confusing you here.  You have something called `question` which contains an array, each of which contains an array, each of which contains a property called `questions`.  The plurality/singularity of those is dizzying.

Perhaps `question` should really be `questionGroups`?  It's an array of arrays.  Each "group" is an array of questions.  Each of which should have a property called `question`.

Variable naming is important, and helps prevent confusion when writing your own code.  So in this case it might be something like:

```
const [questionGroups, setQuestionGroups] = useState([]);

// then later...
questionGroups.map(function (questionGroup){
    questionGroup.map(function (question){
        return question.question;
    })
})
```

Comment: When I use console.log it works, but once I use return it wont print on DOM, why is that? I used your code.

Comment: @YotamDahan: Looks like the outer map isn’t returning anything.  Try putting a “return” before the inner call to map.

Answer (score 0):

In short objects doesn't have .map() function.

Do this instead:
`question.map(function (quest){ return quest.questions; });`